# How is display initiated after sleep mode? Does the BIOS/OS uses the EFI partition?

Tags: display, bios, uefi, efi, system-reserved-partition

I'm having some weird lines displayed in my screen after my computer goes to sleep mode and when I turn it on.

These lines are displayed randomly and I think it has something to do with the EFI partition, so I would like to know if the EFI partition or other disk partitions get somehow involved in this task.

Does Windows access the EFI partition at runtime? Does the EFI partition contain drivers or settings which are involved in turning display on?

Comment: No. However, what type of sleep? Is it hibernation, standby (S3) or connected standby?

Comment: Standby, but It doesn't really matter. I use a program called nircmd to turn the monitor off while Windows keeps running and the lines are shown (randomly) when I use that program

Comment: It actually does matter. When using Standby or nircmd, the UEFI bios is never called, so we can rule out issues related to the UEFI bios. Your problem seems to be driver related. See if there's a driver update that fixes this

Comment: I already tried it and I think that the monitor isn't faulty, so I'll try to carefully figure it out through efi shell. There may be a misconfigured parameter